# Spring 3.0 using radiobutton

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to use radiobutton in Spring.

I have followed this tutorial which works fine:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-radiobutton-and-radiobuttons-example/

However, the tutorial is using Spring 2.5, and I am thinking if there is any other way to do the same in Spring 3.0.

In the above tutorial, custom model is needed in order to store the radio button value.

So is there any way to pass the radio button value directly back to the controller, but not through the custom model?

Something like this in the controller:

```
public void handleExport(@ModelAttribute("exportType") String exportTye)
```

While the exportType is the radio button value.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can access it using @RequestParam :

```
<form:radiobutton path="exportType" value="MyType"/>

public void handleExport(@RequestParam("exportType") String exportTye)
```